# how to modularize/organize java web application

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am creating a j2ee web appp and I have created the following packages

- com.cms.controller (to hold servlets)
- com.cms.business   (to hold busines logic)
- com.cms.dao       (to hold data access objects)
- com.cms.beans  (to hold beans)

Now i want to write a functionality. So i have written a `index.jsp` page which has action = `/loginConroller`.

Now should I do the folling  in `loginController`?

```
Authentication authentication = new Authentication();
boolean flag = authentication.chekLoginCredentials(username, passwd)
```

Will `Authentication` class consist of only one function?
Is this approcach correct?

Comment: What package are you planning to keep Authentication in?

Comment: inside businesss package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would like to get the `User` model from the DAO and check if it is `null` or not. If it is `null`, then display error. If it is not `null`, then put it in session and proceed.

E.g.

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
User user = userDAO.find(username, password);
if (user != null) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
    response.sendRedirect("home");
} else {
    request.setAttribute("error", "Unknown login, please try again.");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("login").forward(request, response);
}
```

Or something like that. With only a `boolean flag` you can't really login the user and you would have to query the DB everytime if you want to get/show details about the logged in user during the session.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be fine, but still you can add some more features that you can get in future which is related to the database like 
1) Closing the connection
2) getting the connection etc